# how can i add a confirm box when users wants to delete something?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to add a confirmation box in below to ask if the user really wants to delete the file.

```
     <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteFileFromPath", "TRecords", new { StrFilename = Server.MapPath(@imgPathArray[imgNum]) })'">
```

the code above works well but don't have a confirm box.

I found some documents in the web, I want to use the javascript method as below

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" onclick="DeleteConfirmBox()">Delete</button>
</form>

<script>
    function DeleteConfirmBox() {
        if (confirm("Do u want to delete the file?")) {
            @Url.Action("DeleteFileFromPath", "TRecords", new { StrFilename = Server.MapPath(@imgPathArray[imgNum]) });
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

the code above seems didn't trigger the DeleteConfirmBox() function, how can I do that to have the confirm box?

Comment: You should look into sweetalert, its a nice confirmation alert. That is if you have the required minimum jQuery files. https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect to your url. Replace this:

```
@Url.Action("DeleteFileFromPath", "TRecords", new { StrFilename = Server.MapPath(@imgPathArray[imgNum]) });
```

with this:

```
location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteFileFromPath", "TRecords", new { StrFilename = Server.MapPath(@imgPathArray[imgNum]) })'
```

Comment: Yes, because @Url.Action prints the literal url. And javascript won't know that it needs to go there.

Comment: David, I changed to that and seemed the redirect go to the index page, if I change the code to location.href = 'www.abc.com', it even won't go to the link www.abc.com ... but it reallys go to the codes in the brackets "if (confirm("Do u want to delete the file?"))" {

Comment: That's what I wrote. You are supposed to change the code in the brackets to redirect to the url. `@Url.Action` only generates the url for you, you need to redirect to it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hello kaihong  modify your code and write button type="button" instead of button type="submit" as written in below code ,Hope it helps.

```
 <form>
<button type="button" onclick="DeleteConfirmBox()">Delete</button>
</form>
<script>
function DeleteConfirmBox() {
    if (confirm("Do u want to delete the file?")) {
    location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteFileFromPath", "TRecords", new { StrFilename = Server.MapPath(@imgPathArray[imgNum]) })';
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works!!! Thank you very very very much Mohan!!!!! I am so exciting!!

Comment: Hello @kaihong don't forget to mark it as a right answer if it works fine.!!

Comment: sorry, Mohan, may be because my reputation is less than 15, i cannot vote, and mark the correct answer